# Howto change live directory with certbot?

Tags: centos7, lets-encrypt, certbot

I using CentOS7 and certbot for make ssl certificate, but the default directory of certificates is "/etc/letsencript/live/first-host" , how to change the forst-host directory with "/etc/letsencript/default" by example?

I using the certbot:

```
certbot certonly --standalone -d host1 -d host2 --debug
```

And the directory:

```
/etc/letsencript/live/host1/
```

Answer (score 1):

the elments in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live` directory are just symlinks to `/etc/letsencrypt/archive/...`.

You can just add another symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/letsencrypt/live/host1/ /etc/letsencrypt/default
```

Comment: what is you didn't want to symlink it but had the root dir somewhere else? Can you specify an option for certbot to look in another DIR?

Comment: Poor solution. I want to BOTH be able to use my own directory name under /live AND have it managed by certbot, e.g. when I later use `certbot delete`.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#where-are-my-certificates, you should be able to use the cli option `--cert-name host1` if you want the generated certificates to be saved in directory `/etc/letsencript/live/host1/`.

Note that this will also have an impact on all certbot commands which deal with certificate management and renewal.